# Can't establish my connection

Tags: firefox, socket.io, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to host a chatting app via google cloud,I have been successful enough on the second attempt, after changing the port number to 8080, just to see the html page.

Now my problem is after inspecting the elements via firefox, I am not able to see the messages show on the screen anymore, which I was successful in seeing when I was hosting it on my pc.

The error messages that I get constantly when trying to send a message is:

With a black X next to it:

```
GET 
http://bla.appspot.com/socket.io/
```

Then:

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://bla/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=5Z6HGjPLI5L2ddNHAADj.
```

After:

```
POST 
XHR 
http://bla.appspot.com/socket.io/

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://bla.appspot.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=5Z6HGjPLI5L2ddNHAADj.
```

And Then:

```
The connection to ws://bla.appspot.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=9Ps_KY0O0UvKfWePAADz was interrupted while the page was loading.
```

The second and third long sentences just constantly rinse and repeat.

I'm not sure as to why socket.io has appeared at the end of the line, but for some reason it has.

Here is my code related to sending and receiving the messages:

```
"use strict";

var app = require ('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
});

http.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:8080');
});
```

And this is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
        *{ margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
        body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
        form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
        form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
        form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
        #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
        #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="messages"></ul>
<form action="">
    <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /> <button>Send</button>
</form>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Could anyone help me with this please? It has been really bugging me a lot and I just can't seem to wrap my head around how to make it work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know if your Google cloud configuration supports webSocket connections (which is what socket.io uses)?  Or, do you know if you have to modify something in your Google cloud configuration in order to support webSocket connections?

Comment: FYI, per [this article](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/real-time-gaming-with-node-js-websocket) and several others, it appears you must use Google Compute Engine for the socket.io server.

Comment: To be honest, I'm still quite the newb when it comes to using Google Cloud. As of now I only know how to make this work locally but not on the cloud. I don't know exactly how to configure google cloud so it does support Websocket connections. I have looked everywhere on how to do this, but haven't quite found HOW to implement this. I have also come across the article you have sent, but it didn't really bring me closer to being able to use Google Compute Enginge.

Comment: I'm not a Google cloud person so I can't help you with the specifics.  I was just trying to direct you to the right things to search for or ask about.  Because socket.io uses webSocket which is a persistent connection, it breaks the original model that a lot of hosting companies used for just handling short connected http requests.  That means you often have to configure something differently or buy/use a different service to get socket.io to work at a hosting site.  For example, more "shared" hosting sites (the less expensive type of hosting) don't support it.

Comment: I do appreciate your help, honestly. I just wish there was some friendly guide out there as to how I can connect this app correctly on the cloud so that I am to see something work. But unfortunately no such material exists out there yet... :(

Comment: I hear you.  I was surprised how little seems to be written about how to do this on Google Cloud.  Many of my searches ended up with dead links which makes it seem like Google may have recently reorganized all their reference information which makes it hard to find (how ironic that Google would mess up search of their own tech resources).  It seems like what you need is an appropriate online forum that is targeted at the Google Cloud Services where Google Cloud people hang out where you could ask for directional information on how to make this work.

Comment: Yes I agree. I think there are hidden keywords I haven't used yet to find what I am looking for. Surely it's out there somewhere, thanks again for your help. :)

Answer (score 2):

So I have figured out my problem.

Turns out that what was causing the actual problem was the line in my code for index.html

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
```

It was working the whole time, but on a different browser, this is because different browsers have different types of security to prevent attacks such as eavesdropping and man-in-the-middle (MITM) attacks.

For example testing this out on Firefox/Chrome would give me the error I have displayed but once I tested it out on IE I was able to see all the messages displayed with the IE exception of leaving the connection "open".

I was able to find more useful errors that helped me reach this conlusion which was `Blocked loading mixed active content` with this I was able to find out that if I removed

```
http:
```

from

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
```

This would stop firefox/chrome from blocking the content.